# Node vs Chrome, implementation of instanceof, multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, typescript, instanceof

I have this weird behavior and hope you can help me. =)

I have a setup where I need to run `JavaScript` tests using `Mocha`. The code is generated from `TypeScript`, and the tests are run in both the browser and `nodejs` via `browserify` and `commonjs` modules. The issue is that I want to use `instanceof`, but apparently the behavior differs depending on whether the code is run in `Node` or in `Chrome`. The example is as follows.

```
// file Actions.ts
Class Action {..}
Class ViewAction extends Action {..}
Class MyViewAction extends ViewAction {..}

// file App.ts
var action = new MyViewAction(); 

// file App.ts or Elsewhere.ts
foo(action) {
    var testA = action instanceof MyViewAction;
    var testB = (<any>action.constructor).name === "MyViewAction";
}
```

The thing is, if foo is called in a different `commonjs` module,
`testA` becomes `false` if run in `Node` but `true` if run in `Chrome`, whereas
`testB` is `true` in both cases.

If foo is run in the same file as action is assigned to,in, the code works consistently.

Can anyone replicate this bug, or explain what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: The reference to `MyViewAction` is present in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

> var action = MyViewAction();

You need to call it with `new` i.e. `new MyViewAction` but I suspect you are already doing this.

> testA becomes false if run in Node but true if run in Chrome

I suspect you have *TWO* `MyViewAction` functions defined.

- In Chrome due to the global namespace the last one wins and the by reference comparison (which is what `instanceof` does) to `MyViewAction` point to the same function.
- In Node each file is its own module and there is no global namespace collision and therefore you have two `MyViewAction` functions and a ref comparison returns false but since they are named the same the `.name` string is same.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did forget 'new' in the description.

Comment: It is a good guess that there may be two definitions of MyViewAction, but I don't think that is the case. I went back and did some more tests and it seems that :

**action instance ViewAction** evaluates to true, 
iff the definition of foo is in another file.

Also I can guarantee there is exactly one place in the codebase where MyViewAction is defined.

Comment: I think this is fairly strange as the constructor name and any stuff I add to MyViewAction clearly is available. =/

Comment: I wonder if two calls to require('MyViewAction') - in App.ts and Elsewhere.ts - could somehow make two MyViewAction functions? Two different context?